# Boolean operator problems

Tags: c++, iostream

Simple code here, I'm trying to write a code that can pick up on specific keywords, but I'm not having a lot of luck. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::string input;
    bool isUnique = true;

    std::cout<<"Please type a word: ";
    std::cin>>input;

    if(input == "the" || "me" || "it"){
        isUnique = false;
    }
    if(isUnique){
        std::cout<<"UNIQUE!!"<<std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout<<"COMMON"<<std::endl;
}
```

If you type in any of those three words (in the if statement), you'll get the proper output from the program ("COMMON"). However, if you type anything else, you'll get that same exact output. If I limit the program to only search for one word (ie: "the") and then test it, everything works as it should, but as soon as there are two or more keywords, the program just lists everything as "COMMON". I've also tried replacing the or statements with commas but that also didn't do anything. The code I'm trying to implement this into is going to have 50+ keywords so I'm trying to find the most efficient way to search for these words.

Comment: `if(input == "the" || input ==  "me" || input == "it"){` That simple! To find from many keywords use a container for them and `std::find()`.

Comment: I suggest you look up how `||` works.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to change:

```
if(input == "the" || "me" || "it")
```

to:

```
if(input == "the" || input == "me" || input == "it")
```

The way operator `||` works in `A || B` is that each clause `A` and `B` is evaluated (if ever) on it's own. `B` does not care about the context of `A`.

So you in your case the following 3 expressions might be evaluated (the last one never):

1. `input == "the"`
2. `"me"`
3. `"it"`

The first one may or may not result in `true`, but the second one definitely will.

---

You can also rewrite your code to:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Please type a word: ";
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    auto common_hints = {"the", "me", "it"};
    if (std::find(begin(common_hints), end(common_hints), input) != end(common_hints)) {
        std::cout << "COMMON\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "UNIQUE!!\n";
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68d62b7096061036)

or (using Boost):

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Please type a word: ";
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    auto common_hints = {"the", "me", "it"};
    if (boost::algorithm::any_of_equal(common_hints, input)) {
        std::cout << "COMMON\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "UNIQUE!!\n";
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa892696b1bc82a7)